# Checking for constexpr in a concept

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, c++-concepts

I just started doing concepts. The syntax for checking expressions is really useful and removes me a lot of boilerplate I had with sfinae. However I wondered how can I check if an expression can be used in a constexpr context. Sometimes those expression results in void. The way I can imagine would look like this, with the constexpr keyword uncommented:

```
template<typename T>
concept foo = requires(T t) {
    /* constexpr */ { t.bar(); } -> std::same_as<void>;
    /* constepxr */ { T::foo; };
}
```

However, I highly doubt this is the right syntax. Is there an easy way to check for the constexpr-ness of the expression in a concept?

I don't want to check if the evaluation of a constexpr function won't fail for all possible values of `t`, I want to know if I can put that expression at a place where the compiler expect something to be evaluable at compile time.

Comment: You can always use the comma operator to change the result type, `constexpr int x = (t.bar(), 0);`

Comment: I don't think it's possible in general - the `constexpr`-ness of `t.bar()` might depend on `t`. What if we had like... `struct X { int i; constexpr void bar() { if (i <= 0) throw 42; }};`

Comment: @Barry hmm... but the function is marked as constexpr, so it is callable in constexpr context. Syntactically, it is allowed. And with the right value, it won't throw. I would consider that throwing in a constexpr function would be more like a runtime requirement, whereas if the function is usealbe at all in constexpr context is more of a compile-time requirement.

Comment: @Barry like, I don't want to ensure that the function won't fail for all possible value, I just want to know if the function can be used in expressions that require compile time evaluation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I was going to make the argument that an `constexpr` is normally evaluated at runtime and that's why checking for `constexpr` shouldn't be allowed but you made a good argument I think for checking an expression to see if it'll be allowed in a constexpr only context (for example an array dimension).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the expected concept can be created using `std::bool_constant`, which has the property that the failure of substitution in its argument of not-constant expression is not a compilation error, but just makes the concept `false`.

The proposed solution is

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept HasConstexprVoidBar = 
requires(T t) {
    { t.bar() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { std::bool_constant<(T{}.bar(), true)>() } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};

struct A {
    constexpr void bar() {}
};

struct B {
    void bar() {}
};

int main() {
    // concept check passes for constexpt A::bar()
    static_assert( HasConstexprVoidBar<A> );
    // concept check fails for B::bar()
    static_assert( !HasConstexprVoidBar<B> );
}
```

Here the concept `HasConstexprVoidBar` is verified successfully for struct `A` having `constexpr void` method `bar` and evaluates to `false` for struct `B` having not-`constexpr` method.

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nsx9z99G4

Comment: This passes my requirements. The syntax is a bit convoluted, but works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
template <typename F, auto Test=std::bool_constant<(F{}(), true)>()>
consteval auto is_constexpr (F) { return Test; }
```

> EDIT: the one I wrote before doesn't work in clang > 13.0 for some reason, but this does

and then

```
requires (T t) {
    is_constexpr([]{ T{}.cols(); });
}
```

Here we use the C++20's consteval func to force constexpr check inside and the fact that since C++20 simple lambdas can be default-constructed, hence we construct it here from F{} and here we go :)